# Subclipse keeps prompting the request for p12 certificate

Tags: svn, subclipse, javahl

I'm using subclipse with eclipse and I have to access to an https repository.
The first time it asked me for the p12 certificate and the passphrase and everything went fine but it keeps prompting me this window any time I explore the repository. Is there a way to store somewhere this information?

I tried to store them in `~/home/myuser/.subversion/config` but it's not working:

```
[groups]
diiga = narg.diiga.univpm.it

[diiga]
ssl-client-cert-file = /home/dierre/Scrivania/NARGSvnUsers.p12
ssl-client-cert-password = mypassphrase
```

Any suggestion? BTW with this config it keeps asking even in the command line.

**UPDATE:** I've partially solved the problem. I went into Preferences/Team/SVN and switch from JavaHL to SVNKit and now the commit and the exploration of the SVN tree are working nicely without asking about it. So now I guess the problem is how to solve it with JavaHL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys, I just want to let you know that the problem was Ubuntu and not Eclipse, because I disabled the keyring so I wasn't able to store anything. Once I renabled it, it worked like a charm.